# Symfony Doctrine : get field value in foreach loop on fetchAll()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fetchall

I'm trying to display some fields of a table 'Post' using a raw query :

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE category_id = 1");
    $statement->execute();
    $posts = $statement->fetchAll();

...

foreach($posts as $post) {
        $xml .= $post->getId();
        $xml .= $post->getTitle();
        $xml .= $post->getContent();
    }
```

I've got an error **"FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in ..."**
All those getters are right in my Post entity. Any suggestion about what I'm doing wrong ?

**[EDIT]**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$post_repository = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Post'); 
$posts = $post_repository->findBy(array('category_id' => 1));

foreach($posts as $post) {
        $xml .= $post->getTitle();
    }
```

Returns me **"Unrecognized field: category_id"**.

My Post class :

```
class Post
{
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="post")
* @ORM\JoinColumns({
*  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* })
*/
private $category;
/**
* Set category
*
@param MyBundle\Entity\Category $category
*/
public function setCategory(\MyBundle\Entity\Category $category)
{
    $this->category = $category;
}
/**
* Get category
*
@return MyBundle\Entity\Category
*/
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

....
```

Comment: Presumably your actual sql is (or will be) more complex than the code you have given here, as with symfony/doctrine raw queries are only rarely used when the higher level mechanisms are insufficient. A simple repository->findBy() would suffice for this sql

Comment: Why do you use raw sql for such simple cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using directly your connection here? You should consider using the entity repository for your "posts" class. For example :

```
$posts = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Post')->findBy(array('category_id' => 1));
```

this should work, just replace the `YourBundle:Post` with the proper bundle and class names. Same for the `category_id`, I can't guess without your implementation if it's the class property or the mapping name.

I suggest you to read more on [the official Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html) to improve your knowledge on the subject.

Comment: This might be indeed better ! Now I have an error "Unrecognized field: category_id ". This field is the foreign key in reference to my Category class (many-to-one).

Comment: Then, can you add in your original post the copy/paste of your "Post" class please Static Wizard?

Comment: Oh, ok, now I get it... category_id is the database field, but what I have to use is "category" mapped in my class... At least I've learnt from my mistake ! Thank you for your advice !

Comment: That's exactly it! My bad for not seeing it previously! Glad it helped :)

Comment: this saved my day

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a raw query using Doctrine's DBAL layer the results come back as an array of field names mapped to values rather than as entities.

Therefore you need something like this:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $xml .= $post['id'];
    $xml .= $post['title'];
    $xml .= $post['content';
}
```